# regex expression in Python to select code based on the first 4 digits

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to write regex expression in python.

For the following text:

```
9430 123 12345
5322 123 12345
3441 123 12345
```

I need to extract only the two line that begin with 5322 and 9430. All other codes should be ignored.
I used the following expression:

```
patfinder1 = re.compile('((5322|9430))(\s\d{3}\s\d{5})')
patsearch = re.findall(patfinder1, search_str)
```

but is giving me too many matches in place of getting the two lines
result:

```
('9430', '9430', ' 123 12345')
('5322', '5322', ' 123 12345')
```

I also tried many different expressions but still did not find the right one.

Comment: Convert all your capturing groups into non-capturing. `(?:5322|9430)(?:\s\d{3}\s\d{5})`

Comment: It works now. Thanks